# Converting Date "2016-06-03" to "03 JUNE 2016" in Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have date format as `"2016-06-03"` and I have to convert it as below :

`"03 JUNE 2016"`.

I have tried as below :

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
 String newFormat = formatter.format("2016-06-03");
```

But, getting below error :

```
Invalid Arguments Exception
```

Please, help me to solve out this. Thanks.

Comment: try using switch for the month number and you will get what you want.

Comment: Possible, But, not a good idea..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This common function for convert date format

```
public static SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
public static SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
public static String formattedDate = "";

public static String getFormattedDate(String targetPattern,
                                      String existingPattern, String existingValue) {
    formattedDate = existingValue;
    targetFormat.applyPattern(targetPattern);
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
    symbols.setAmPmStrings(new String[] { "AM", "PM" });
    targetFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(symbols);
    originalFormat.applyPattern(existingPattern);
    try {
        formattedDate = targetFormat.format(originalFormat
                .parse(existingValue));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return formattedDate;
}
```

and used like

```
 String txtdate = getFormattedDate("dd MMMM yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd","2016-06-03");
```

Comment: Thanks, Just MMMM in place of MMM.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use DateFormat instead of SimpleDateFormat :

```
//Should print something like June 27, 2016
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.ENGLISH);
String format = df.format(yourDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public String convert_date(String date)
 {
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     java.util.Date d = null;
 try 
 {
     d = df.parse(date);
 } catch (ParseException e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
     df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
     return   df.format(d);
 }

**String convertedDate = convert_date("2016-06-25");**
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code copy it from here its working fine now

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String newFormat = null;
        try {
            newFormat = formatter.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-06-03"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Date", ": " + newFormat);
```

**output**

```
D/Date: : 03 June 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get the month from the calendar in android you generally get the month number not the name. but if you want to get name of it you can get it in two ways.

1. To get the full name-

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
   String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
   ```
2. To get the short name of month-

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
   String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
   ```

*For more information on the SimpleDateFormat class please look - [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month) .*